# Make vertical figures overlap in latex

Tags: spacing, graphics, floats

I want to put two figures into a multicolumn document that span both columns. I want to move the two figures closer together vertically so that they slightly overlap. The two figures fit together like a puzzle, so trimming them is not an option. How can I make the two figures overlap?

Here is my attempt:

```
\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{figure1.pdf} \\ \vspace*{-1cm}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{figure2.pdf} \\    
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{caption goes here}
\end{figure*}
```

The `\vspace*`command does not do anything inside of the `tabular` environment, but hopefully it gets the idea across -- a vertical shift in the figures to make them overlap. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: inside the `tabular` environment, you should be able to end a line with `\\[-1cm]` to do what you want.  that is the equivalent of a negative `\vspace` outside of `tabular`.

Comment: Excellent! I was hoping it was as simple as that, I just couldn't find the command. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

the tabular is doing nothing useful there, simply

```
\begin{figure*}
  \centering

    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{figure1.pdf} 

    \vspace*{-1cm}

    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{figure2.pdf}   

  \caption{caption goes here}
\end{figure*}
```